# 1980-1990’s sci-fi novel – Therapist uses empathic abilities to rehabilitate hardened criminals on a prison planet

Tags: story-identification, novel

Want to locate novel about therapist (not called that) who uses empathic abilities to rehabilitate hardened criminals on a prison planet (or space prison). Futuristic and humanistic ideas of justice and individual worth.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F :) - This is a good start, but are there any further details that you can add to the question?  Take the tour as well - https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 3):

You don't give a lot of information, but a possibility is [The Fear Principle by B.A. Chepaitis](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2037444.The_Fear_Principle) published in 2011.

[image: The Fear Principle]

> Dr. Jaguar Addams knows about fear. On a satellite prison called Planetoid Three, she establishes a telepathic link to her subjects. She confronts their demons. And makes them her own. They were known as the Killing Times, when serial murder reached epidemic proportions. Victims of hard-edged crime demanded hard-wired punishment, and the new prisons were born. Now one determined woman, a survivor of that dark age, tries to rehabilitate killers by tapping into the source of their obsessions: their worst fears. Her name is Jaguar Addams, and she is about to face the most challenging subject of her career. The ultimate assassin. A dangerously disturbed woman who will teach Jaguar the true meaning of fear.

I have the book, though I don't remember much about it. If you remember any other key points about the story I can check them in my copy of the book to see if they match.